# Once you have a set of training data, how do you go about training a model?

Tags: distributions, dataset, train

I've been trying to teach myself machine learning using some books, kaggle and other resources so I'm still very new at this. I'm trying to do a competition on kaggle and I've obtained a dataset.

I'm a little confused about what exactly needs to **be done** with this data set next though.  My assumption is that if I choose to use a univariate distribution to model this data, I need to pick the features(columns in my csv file) I want to use, somehow combine them into a single variable xi and pass each pair of values of and labels (xi,yi) into my model, adjusting the model's parameters to fit the data.

I'm assuming that if I chose a bivariate distribution to model this data, I would do something similar, except I would convert the features of my choice into two separate values x1,x2 and pass tuples (xi1,xi2,yi) into my model and adjust parameters to fit the data.

for an n-variate distribution I would do... the same thing and pass in a vector (xi1, ..., xin, yi) into my model.

Is this pattern of thinking correct? I know I'm not mentioning anything about model or feature selection but that's mainly because I feel like I need to understand this step between training data --> model before I can even try to implement a likelihood estimation algorithm or pick the features I want to use.

Also please correct any terminology I've misused as I still have no idea what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, probably a (competitive) Kaggle dataset is not the best dataset to start with.  There are many university courses and textbooks online that have exercises specially designed for beginners.

I think you're confusing **modelling a distribution** (simplified: does this histogram look like a normal distribution or a uniform distribution) and **modelling the relationship** between the outcome $y$ and the predictors $x$ (given $x$, what is our estimate of $y$).

You have a bunch of training data, for which you know the mapping between $x$ (which might be a vector / tuple with $n$ elements) and $y$ (a scalar).  Your task is to learn the relationship between $x$ and $y$, so that you can predict the $y$ value for other values of $x$.  The first thing to consider is: Is your $y$ qantitative (can it have arbitrary numerical values, at least within some range) or is it categorical (only certain values, maybe not even numerical, i.e. 'yes'/'no', 'red'/'green'/'black')?  For the first scenario, you want to perform a *regression*, for the latter a *classification*.

For your first problems, you don't have to perform feature selection or feature engineering.  You also don't have to try to select the best kind of model -- just pick whatever you want to learn (or what is suggested by the exercise).

In this case, the step from training data to a model is quite easy:  Your model will simply have as many inputs as your problem has predictors: For linear regression you use a model with $n+1$ parameters (one for each input plus the offset); for a neural network you select $n$ input nodes; $k$-nearest neighors will work in $n$-dimensional space.  You train the model with the training data according to the training equations/algorithm (either you do some calculations by hand, or you use a compute library for it or you write your own program) and can then use the trained model to predict new instances (again: either calculate by hand or use a library or write some code).

Where to go from there?  You should learn to do your modelling using a computer program (e.g. R, Weka, Numpy); try different types of models (linear regression, neural network, regression trees, SVM); learn metrics to compare different models (mean squared error; accuracy) and how to properly do this (training/test sets, cross validation, bootstrap); learn about overfitting (and bias and variance) and ways to prevent it (regularization); learn how to deal with the curse of dimensionality (normalization, feature engineering, feature selection).  And tackle real-world problems.